Inserting data from excel into word template with multiple excel files
I have a folder of daily transaction statements that are stored in a csv format. I want to find a way to insert that that into a monthly account statement. I have tried using Mail merge and setting it up to insert certain columns at targeted areas to create a template for one entry but how would I go about doing this for multiple excel files to automate the creation of a monthly account statement? Would it be possible to set it up so that mail merge can take the formatting for row and copy that for each of the rows in the excel file?
Edit:
My input file is a csv file containing the transactions done for the month in the columns (e.g date, companyName, amount ...). The amount of transaction represented by rows is not fixed.
What I would like as an output is a word doc that follows another word doc as a template. In this template it displays the data obtained from in the following format for each row. Currently the data is manually copy and pasted for each row and I was looking for a  way to automate this process.

Difficult to tell based on what you have said so far. Can you edit your question with an example of what you are starting with and what you want to output?

Unless I'm missing something, it seems like the article on microsoft.com explains quite well how to:

"mail merge can take the formatting for row and copy that for each of the rows in the excel file"

Just pop open one of those drop downs in step 1 on that link and follow the instructions to import the csv directly.
But I'm probably missing something, so help me understand.
